# Spring JPA Hibernate DeleteByColumnName behaves very inefficient

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to use the Spring's `CrudRepository` work with Hibernate to delete rows by a non-primary-key column, using `deleteByColumnName` method. However, the actual executed query is very inefficient and too slow in practice.

Suppose I have two tables `Project` and `Employee`, and each employee is in charge of some projects, which implies that the `Project` table has a field `employee_id`. Now I would like to delete some projects by `employee_id`. I wrote something like

```java
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, String> {
    @Transactional
    void deleteByEmployeeId(String employeeId);
}
```

What I am expecting is Hibernate will execute the following query for this method

```
DELETE FROM Project
WHERE employee_id = ?
```

**However, Hibernate executes it in a drastically slow way like**

```
SELECT id FROM Project
WHERE employee_id = ?
```

Hibernate stores the above result in a list, and execute

```
DELETE FROM Project
WHERE id = ?
```

for `N` times... (it executes in batch though)

To address this inefficiency problem, I have to override the method by writing SQL directly, like

```java
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, String> {
    @Query("DELETE FROM Project p where p.employee_id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void deleteByEmployeeId(String employeeId);
}
```

Then the behavior will be exactly the same as what I am expecting.

The performance is substantially distinct when I delete about 1k rows in a table containing around 500k entries. **The first method will take 45 seconds to finish the deleting compared to the second methods taking only 250ms!**

The reason I use Hibernate is taking advantage of its ORM strategy that avoids the use of SQL language directly, which is easy to maintain in the long run. At this point, is there anyone who know how to let Hibernate execute the deletion in the manner of my second method without directly writing the SQL? Is there something I am missing to optimize the Hibernate performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you enable hibernate batch support

Comment: To delete savely hibernate needs to obtain the entities first. The same happens if you do a `deleteById`. Without the entity it doesn't know about the relations it has and what to delete (could be that it needs to delete additional entities due to relations in the entity). Spring Data has a `deleteAllInBatch` which executes a query underneath. So if you want to directly execute the query the only way is to specify the query yourself.

Comment: @MaxExplode Thank you for your comment. I did enable the batch and it does execute in batch. However, that running the query "delete from table where id = ?" 
 a lot of time is the bottleneck slowing down the execution, while "delete from table where another_field = ?" only executes once.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a good explanation why Hibernate has this bad performace when deleting Project items  [Best Practices for Many-To-One and One-To-Many Association Mappings](https://thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/)

Comment: Hi, welcom to stackoverflow. Please post some info directly instead of sharing the link. Because links can become broken/dead in the future.

Comment: Thank you, this article is really useful. So at this point, that avoid Hibernate default operation, override the method with raw query, and handle the relationship myself is the only way to solve the efficiency problem, correct?

Comment: Yes, you should write your own DELETE statement.